# Android no set default values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I followed all [the instructions for setting default preference values](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Defaults) step by step but does not work.

1º I set the default values:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_game" >
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1.5"
        android:entries="@array/intervale_count"
        android:entryValues="@array/intervale_count_values"
        android:key="interval"
        android:title="@string/interval" />
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/mode_normal"
        android:entries="@array/mode_game"
        android:entryValues="@array/mode_game_values"
        android:key="mode"
        android:title="@string/mode" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_sound" >
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/stone"
        android:entries="@array/time_sounds"
        android:entryValues="@array/time_sounds_values"
        android:key="time_sounds"
        android:title="@string/sounds_stones" />
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/vuvucela"
        android:entries="@array/gong_sounds"
        android:entryValues="@array/gong_sounds_values"
        android:key="gong_sounds"
        android:title="@string/sounds_gong" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

2º I get the preferences in my `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
}
```

But when I open the preference view no preferences are selected, the strings of I declare in the `android:defaultValue` is the SAME as one of the options Ihave in the array of data in `android:entries`.

Note: I try to change to `true` the boolean in

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

but that still does not work.

I've also tried to uninstall and delete the data of the app but that still does not work.

Edit: the array values

```
<string-array name="intervale_count">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>1.3</item>
    <item>1.5</item>
    <item>1.7</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="intervale_count_values">
    <item>1000</item>
    <item>1300</item>
    <item>1500</item>
    <item>1700</item>
    <item>2000</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="mode_game">
    <item>@string/mode_normal</item>
    <item>@string/mode_extension</item>
    <item>@string/mode_infinite</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="mode_game_values">
    <item>100</item>
    <item>50</item>
    <item>1000</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="time_sounds">
    <item>@string/alan</item>
    <item>@string/cash_reg</item>
    <item>@string/censure</item>
    <item>@string/crow</item>
    <item>@string/doh</item>
    <item>@string/fb_noti</item>
    <item>@string/achievement</item>
    <item>@string/metal_gear</item>
    <item>@string/duck</item>
    <item>@string/pan</item>
    <item>@string/drum</item>
    <item>@string/stone</item>

</string-array>
   <string-array name="time_sounds_values">
    <item>2131099648</item> <!-- Alan -->
    <item>2131099649</item> <!-- Registradora -->
    <item>2131099650</item> <!-- Censura -->
    <item>2131099651</item> <!-- Cuervo -->
    <item>2131099652</item> <!-- DOh -->
    <item>2131099653</item> <!-- FB -->
    <item>2131099655</item> <!-- logro -->
    <item>2131099656</item> <!--metal gear  -->
    <item>2131099657</item> <!-- pato -->
    <item>2131099658</item><!-- sarten -->
    <item>2131099660</item> <!-- tambor -->
    <item>2131099659</item><!-- stone -->
</string-array>
<string-array name="gong_sounds">
    <item>@string/gong</item>
    <item>@string/vuvucela</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="gong_sounds_values">
    <item>2131099654</item> <!--  Gong -->
    <item>2131099661</item> <!-- Vuvucela -->
</string-array>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what one of your entries and one of your entryValues looks like? For example, post both `@array/gong_sounds` and `@array/gong_sounds_values`.

Comment: Thank you for u response, i just edit the question! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defaultValue` attribute for a `ListPreference` needs to be a value, not the entry text. In other words, it should be an element in the array you pass to `android:entryValues`, not an element in the array you pass to `android:entries`.

For example, your gong sounds preference should use `android:defaultValue="2131099661"` instead of `android:defaultValue="@string/vuvucela"`

Comment: No works, for example, the 1º default value is "android:defaultValue="1.5" " and no works, and now i try to do in the others and the same, If that were so, putting only the content, what would happen when the app translate?

Comment: For your first preference, your entries (the `intervale_count` array) are decimals between 1 and 2, but the values (the `intervale_count_values` array) are integers between 1000 and 2000. The value that corresponds with the entry of "1.5." is 1500.

Comment: As for translation- this is exactly why you need to use the keys (the values) instead of the entries (the text that is displayed). The text will be translated, so it can't be used as a key to find the default value. Think of the entries and values as key-value pairs, where the keys are your `entryValues` and the values are your `entries`.

Comment: Aaah, okay, i understand now, and works! Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work, try to wipe the app data from the emulator/device and then reinstall the app. After I did that in my project and followed Tanis hints, it worked like a charm.